# No inserta dato. desde el input entre django y postgres

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

**catalogo / urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from catalogos.views import CategoriaView,CategoriaNew

urlpatterns =[
    .....

    path('categorias/new', CategoriaNew.as_view(),name='categoria_new'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoriaNew(generic.CreateView):
    model=Categoria
    template_name = "catalogos/categoria_form.html"
    context_object_name = 'obj'
    form_class=CategoriaForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("catalogos:categoria_list")
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms

from catalogos.models import  Categoria

class CategoriaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Categoria
        fields=['descripcion']
        labels= {'descripcion':'Descripcion de las categoria'},
        widget = {'descripcion':forms.TextInput()}

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class':'form-control'
            })
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block contenido %}
    <form mehthod="POST">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel panel-heading">
                    Editar/ crear categorias
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-save"></span> Guardar</button>
                <a href="{% url 'catalogos:categoria_list' %}" class="btn btn-success " ><span class="fa fa-undo">Cancelar</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock contenido %}
```

**catalogo_list**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <a href="{% url 'catalogos:categoria_new' %}" class="btn btn-info"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> Nueva</a>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for item in obj %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.descripcion }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock contenido %}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Uso:linux, postgres 10 ,django 2.0

  En la function **reverse_lazy("catalogos:categoria_list")** no hace el redirect, ni me esta insertando el dato en la tabla  ¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo?

Comment: que te devuelve el servidor!?

Comment: CIL4N&descripcion=insertoestedato HTTP/1.1" 200 15402
Not Found: /favicon.ico

Comment: Añade la definición de la clase Categoria.

Comment: para el redirect usa .....success_url = "/catalogos/categoria_list"

Comment: fijate esta linea...form mehthod="POST"...deberia ser...form method="POST"

Comment: listo lo solucione corrigiendo el method='POST' e  instalando pip install psycopg2-binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución esta en corregir el mehthod="POST" por **method='POST'**, estoy utilizando  el editor pycharm al instalar  con pip el  **psycopg2-binary**, funciona bien la inserción de datos